# Previously working Google App Script now produces permission error

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I cannot find anything about Google having updated policies on April 2022. This script was working without any issues before, then in the middle of the day, permissions needed to be re-added. Even with said permissions granted, Google still says access is denied. It was later discovered that the macro has not ran successfully since March 31st.

```
  var newJobFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newJobID);
  newJobFile.AddEditors(['group@gmail.com','admin@gmail.com');
  newJobFile.setOwner('admin@gmail.com');
```

The last line is what generates the error. When debugging, I can see as the variable gets created, I cannot see any information about it. For example, if I add a "Filecreated.getName();" before the line with the error, the variable menu remains blank. I am not sure if this is normal. The "newid" variable is confirmed to have the spreadsheet ID. I can copy it into the URL and it takes me to the page. Why is this suddenly an issue and how can I fix it? I did not have a appscripts.json file before with OAuthScopes and it worked fine then. I've added it with the proper permissions, but it does not change anything. I've added several permission scopes to try to resolve this but none of them do. Any advice?

```json
"oauthScopes": [      
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]
```

EDIT: I am still having this issue. Even with everything controlled under one account, I cannot transfer ownership to 'Central_account@gmail.com' due to 'Exception : Access Denied : DriveApp'. I have found just one other person experiencing this same issue on the Google App Script group page. Is anyone else not having issues with transferring ownership starting in April on a regular, non-work account?

EDIT 2: Sorry for not uploading my code earlier, I had to clean it up first.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Add')    //creates toolbar entry to the right of 'Help'
      .addItem('Capital project','newProject')
      .addToUi();
}

function newProject(){
  var dashboard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    //Stores dashboard into a variable for later
  var template = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx')    //Opens the project sheet template in the backend
  var nameEntry = getName();                                //Prompts user for the name of the new job file
  if (nameEntry == null){
    return;
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(template);            //Template is now the active sheet

  var newJobID = copySheet(nameEntry);                    //Creates a copy of the New Project template
  var newJobFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newJobID);

  newJobFile.AddEditors(['group@gmail.com','admin@gmail.com');
  newJobFile.setOwner('admin@gmail.com');
}

function getName(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var name = ui.prompt(                                      //Prompts the user for an input name      
    '',
    '?????-? Project Description',
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var cancelCheck = name.getSelectedButton();
  if (cancelCheck == ui.Button.CANCEL || cancelCheck == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    return null;
  } 
  var sheetName = name.getResponseText();
  return sheetName;
}

function copySheet(name) {
  var activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newFile = activeSS.copy(name)                       //Creates a copy of the New Project template

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(newFile);              //Resets active spreadsheet to the recent copy
  activeSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  activeSS.getRange('A1').activateAsCurrentCell();
  activeSS.getCurrentCell().setValue(name);                  //Set cell A1 to the name of the file

  var newHyperlink = '=HYPERLINK("' + activeSS.getUrl() + '#gid=15580246",A1)';
  activeSS.getRange('A2').activateAsCurrentCell();
  activeSS.getCurrentCell().setValue(newHyperlink);

  return activeSS.getId();
}
```

With logs, I can see that everything works as intended except for the .setOwner() method. It returns the Access Denied error. I have checked all google accounts and each has enabled CustomScripts to access their drive. Has .setOwner() been deprecated for non workspace accounts?

I've updated my original snippets to match my code.

Comment: I got an email the other day about this. Google discontinued implicit authorization flow so if you're using this type of authorization flow in the browser, this could be causing your issue. How are you calling the function in the Google Apps Script?

Comment: Also, have you tried checking your project in the Google cloud console?

Comment: @vinkomlacic It's called by using onOpen function which creates a toolbar menu I call "New" and under it allows users to run 1 of 3 functions which copies the respective template for the function. I'm not sure what you mean by checking my project in the cloud console

Comment: You can assign a Google Cloud project to Google Apps Scripts, but I guess if you don't know about it, you probably didn't use it and that's not where the problem is :). Have you tried clearing the cookies or running it in the private browser? It could be that an old invalid token is being passed each time

Comment: Tried both without success. From what I can tell, what they discontinued was for 3rd party apps using google sign-in. This script is based in a spreadsheet and doesn't operate outside of google drive.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error you're getting? Also, I see you're using the method [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid) which requires the following scope and don't see it in your code: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

Comment: @LorenaGomez It throws an "Exception : Access Denied : DriveApp" on the .setOwner() line and does not have any other notes. I tried adding that permission, but it did not work. Would not having the scope for "../auth/drive" be enough anyway? or should the permissions be more refined

Comment: Just to confirm, has the script worked before under the same account you're using now? Is this script running in a Google Workspace account or regular Gmail account?

Comment: Yes, the script has worked for two years with all accounts remaining the same. Then, suddenly says Access Denied when trying to use the .setOwner() method. The last successful run was March 31st. The accounts were asked again to allow CustomScripts access to drive files beginning April when they had not been asked since their first time using it (at different periods of year). It is running in a regular Gmail account.

Comment: I have seen in a Google App Script community post that at least one other person has experienced this issue with the .setOwner() method. I have not seen anywhere say it is deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the process to transfer file ownership between consumer accounts has changed. According to this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing#transfer_file_ownership_from_one_consumer_account_to_another_consumer_account), the prospective new owner needs to accept the transfer request. See example below:
[image]

And I found this [article](https://www.cloudwards.net/transfer-ownership-google-drive/#:%7E:text=Transfer%20Ownership%20of%20the%20Folder%20to%20the%20New%20Owner) where you can see that the process was different a few months ago, you could set a new owner immediately without sending invitation.

[image]

I tested the setOwner() method with a Google Workspace account and it works as within Google Workspace you can directly transfer file ownership between users within the same organization, then I tested the same script with a Gmail account and tried to set another Gmail account as the new owner and I got the same error message: "Exception: Access denied: DriveApp".

Based on all the information, it seems that this behavior is expected as the process to change a file ownership for Gmail accounts is different now, you can’t set a new owner directly, the person you invite to own the file must accept your request to complete the transfer.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes sense as to what I’m seeing

Comment: How is this flow done in code? How do you invite the user to own the file and how do you accept it and how do you know if is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I'd second what Lorena Gomez said that it's likely an issue with your OAuthScopes. According to the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setowneruser), the `setOwner()` method on the File class requires the /auth/drive authorization scope.

It looks like you have both the /auth/drive and the /auth/drive.file scope configured, and I think the /auth/drive.file scope, which is narrower, is overriding the broader /auth/drive scope, which is required to call `setOwner()`.

Have you tried removing the /auth/drive.file scope and running the script only with /auth/drive?

Comment: I had started with "/auth/drive". Each new authorization I added later to try to see if that was the one I needed. However, I did just try to remove the more refined authorizations again, and it throws the same "Exception : Access Denied : DriveApp" when trying to .setOwner()

Comment: Just to be clear, all the accounts involved are @gmail.com accounts, right? Google Workspace doesn't allow transferring file ownership across domains. Two other thoughts are: 1) Is the file that you assign to `filecreated` a file type other than common types like a Google Editor document or a PDF? I think there might be issues with transferring ownership of certain file types; and 2) have you double checked that the account executing the script is already the owner of the file you're getting? Only Owners can transfer ownership, not Editors or other permission levels.

Comment: I should have uploaded my code sooner, and for that I apologize. It is a regular Google spreadsheet that I use as a template. I make a copy of it into my google drive and then set the owner as the Admin account. It worked for two years, then suddenly stopped due to Access Denied. The entire code works as intended except when transferring ownership of the google spreadsheet. It isn't a syntax or file type issue. Did Google deprecate the .setOwner() method for non-workspace accounts?